# Ceon SEO URl gives the error page not found in zen cart

Tags: php, .htaccess, zen-cart, zen

I have installed a zen cart plugin `"Ceon's SEO URL"`.

Admin panel has no errors in the installation but on the site when I click on the Product name it shows 404 error.

I am trying to follow  installation steps of ceon's plugin but I am facing the problem

```
8.Add the Rewrite Rule to the Webserver (Apache/IIS etc.)
```

so please help me.

I have this .htaccess file on this path `htdocs\zencarttest\zencart` and my .htaccess is as folow

```
## BEGIN CEON URI MAPPING REWRITE RULE

RewriteEngine On

# ONLY rewrite URIs beginning with /zencarttest/zencart/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/zencarttest/zencart/ [NC]

# Don't rewrite any URIs ending with a file extension (ending with .[xxxxx])
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html)$ [NC]




# Don't rewrite any URIs for some specific file format extensions,
#   which are not covered by main file extension condition above
#   Uncomment the following line to apply this condition! (Remove the # at the start of the next line)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(3gp|3g2|h261|h263|mj2|mjp2|mp4v|mpg4|m1v|m2v|m4u|f4v|m4v|3dml)$ [NC]

# Don't rewrite admin directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/zencarttest/zencart/admin_test [NC]

# Don't rewrite editors directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/zencarttest/zencart/editors/ [NC]

# Handle all other URIs using Zen Cart (its index.php)
RewriteRule .* /zencarttest/zencart/index.php [QSA,L]

## END CEON URI MAPPING REWRITE RULE
```

Where did I make a mistake??

Please help me! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Did you write that .htaccess file yourself or you used the automatically generated .htaccess file? If you go to admin->Modules->Ceon URI Config, select Installation Check and click on the Check Installation link, you will get a generated .htaccess file which you need to place in your store's root (in your case htdocs\zencarttest\zencart). If you're still getting a 404, try removing the slash here:

```
# Handle all other URIs using Zen Cart (its index.php)
RewriteRule .* /zencarttest/zencart/index.php [QSA,L]
```

so you get:

```
# Handle all other URIs using Zen Cart (its index.php)
RewriteRule .* zencarttest/zencart/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Also, make sure your server has mod_rewrite installed (I've seen some that didn't have it).

Comment: if i am put `RewriteRule .* zencarttest/zencart/index.php [QSA,L]` then the index page have 404 error and with "/" index page is display and also products are display perfectly but when i am try to click on other link like about us,Shipping & Returns ect at thet time it will gives me 404 error

Comment: hello @user1078494 how can i set old page url means "Contact Us,Site Map" because it give me 404 error product page and newly create page from "EZ pages" are work fine. So i need your help to change url of already existing page.. Please help me

Comment: you'd get more answers on the official forum, that's for sure. Conor (the module's author) is there and provides support. :) Anyway, please read the second post which explains how to do it [link]http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?184548-Ceon-URI-Mapping-v4-x[/link] - in short, you'll need to add those using phpmyadmin, there's no other easy way. Well, actually, there is - you can buy his URI Mapping Manager and then you have complete control from the admin. I purchased it and it's really worth it. Check his site: [link]http://ceon.net/software/business/zen-cart/uri-mappings-manager[/link]